# использование extensions в swift в классах

Tags: swift, extension

Не могу понять можно использовать extensions c классами?

к примеру у меня есть такой код:

```
extension HelloEveryBody {

    func addString() -> String {
        return "hhhh \(self)"
    }
}

class HelloEveryBody {

    var abc = "hello"

    func helloAgain() {

        print(abc.addString())
    }
}

var test = HelloAgain()

test.helloAgain()
```

Почему данный код не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там в ошибках компилятора все объясняется

1)

```
print(abc.addString())
```

abc это строка (типа String), у строки нет функции addString (это функция вашего класса HelloEveryBody)

2)

```
var test = HelloAgain()
```

в вашей программе (по крайней мере в той части, которую вы показали) нет класса HelloAgain. Видимо вы хотели создать объект класса HelloEveryBody

Ну и чтобы все это работало, можно переписать например так

```
class HelloEveryBody {

    var abc = "hello"

    func helloAgain() {

        print(self.addString())
    }
}

extension HelloEveryBody {

    func addString() -> String {
        return "hhhh \(self.abc)"
    }
}


var test = HelloEveryBody()

test.helloAgain()
```

Comment: yess! i can seee....